# Issue with cleaning LINQ Cache and DataContext

Tags: c#, sql-server, caching, linq-to-sql

I'm working right now in a big project designed with a N-Tier architecture, developed using Visual Studio 2008 and MSSQL Server 2005. In the project was used a Repository Pattern with Dependency Injection using Unity.

The first problem appears when in the moment of the insert, update, etc operations in the database the data were not inserted or updated in the moment, had to close the application an reopen to view the new data.

After a long reading it was discovered that the problem was the LINQ Cache that was not properly cleaned. We solved the problem inserting in the class that all Entities implement the following method :

```
public void ClearCache()
{
   DataContextFactory.GetDataContextInstance(true);
   Context.Log = Console.Out;
}
```

And this is the `DataContextFactory` class :

```
public static class DataContextFactory
{
    public static PromedDataContext Context;

    public static PromedDataContext GetDataContextInstance(bool recreate)
    {
        return Context != null && !recreate ? Context : (Context = new PromedDataContext(GlobalAttributesProvider.DbConnectionPath));
    }
}
```

The solution was to create a new instance of the DataContext and every time you it is inserted or updated values , after call to the above `ClearCache` method.

The problem is that after a while this solution works, but in one moment began to appears another problem when I tried to insert data in the database. The error was the following :

`We attempted to attach or add an entity that is not new. Perhaps he had loaded another DataContext element. This operation is not supported.`

After reading a while for this error , I solved just commenting the body of the `ClearCache` method, because  this was creating multiple instances of the `DataContext` and of course this broke my solution to the cache in pieces.

My question is :

There is another way to clean the mentioned Cache avoiding the above error? 
Or to fix the above error leaving intact the `ClearCache` method?

Thanks in advance

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataContext` is supposed to live as long as a "**unit of work**" takes. For web apps this is usually a single HTTP request.

You are sharing the `DataContext` for all work that is being done. It is not supposed to be used that way. The entities in it are not a cache. They are essential to keep DB state and in-memory state synchronized.

Research what unit of work means in the context of LINQ to SQL and apply best practices. At the moment you are misusing the framework and will have to perform extreme contortions to get it to work.